# Postgis overlapping two linestrings

Tags: postgis, overlapping

I need a specific function to get if two linestring overlaps.
e.g.
Linestring 1 is Point (0, 0) : Point (10, 0)
Linestring 2 is Point (0, 0) : Point (3, 0)

In this case I need "true" result because LineString 1 overlaps in different points like 0,0  1,0    2,0 &  3,0. I dont need the common points, I only need if two linestring overlaps or not.
I tried with this function in postgis...

overlaps(buffer(LINESTRING1, 0.001), buffer(LINESTRING2, 0.001))
I create a buffer on both linestrings... but muy problem is some times works better, some times not.

Can you help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of understanding the spatial predicate terminology used by the [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM), which isn't always intuitive. You don't want "overlaps", but more likely mean "intersects" (i.e. `ST_Intersects`).

See [JTS TestBuilder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/what-free-programs-should-every-gis-user-have-installed/12119#12119) to get a better understanding of the spatial predicate meanings for different geometry configurations.